# How to use create classes using third party interface java

Tags: design-patterns

I have an interface

```
interface Sound  {
 createsound()
}
```

and I have second interface in another library

```
interface Soundable
{
   makesound
}
```

and classes that implenets one of this interfaces
I need make changes in the code to use it like this

```
System.out.println(creature.createSound());
```

witch design pattern should i use to use classes that implements the `Soundable` interface?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) will do. Create a class that wraps `Soundable` and implements `Sound` by delegating the call to `createsound` to the wrapped `Soundable.makesound`.

Comment: if you want to treat several object like a single one.  What should I use ? smells like composite? Thanks.

Comment: if my instance makesound() and i need to take corresponding actions in real time (some methods).  Can i achieve that using observer?

Comment: you should better formulate your question (or create new ones) to have better answers...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [adapter pattern](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).